# Get device specifications from UDID

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, udid

Is it possible get to a device's specifications from a UDID? For instance, if it's an iPad or iPhone.

Or are UDIDs just completely random?

Comment: UDID's are generated randomly. The only reason they are unique is because of the sheer improbability of creating two equal UDIDs. Having said that, you can't get the UDID anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get UDID of device, see [link](http://www.macworld.com/article/2031573/apple-sets-may-1-deadline-for-udid-iphone-5-app-changes.html)

However, You can get some device's specifications (iOS version, model name...) from UIDevice instance:

```
var myDevice = UIDevice.currentDevice()
```

About device type (iphone/ipad):
with iOS < 8, you can check

`if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)`

with iOS>= 8, you can retrieve this info from UITraitCollection, property `userInterfaceIdiom`